# NIL when Parsing JSON

Tags: ios, json, swift

I am trying to parse and get the values from this structure of JSON:

```
["mst_customer": 1, "data": {
    0 = 2;
    1 = 1;
    2 = 1;
    3 = "JAYSON TAMAYO";
    4 = "581-113-113";
    5 = 56;
    6 = on;
    7 = g;
    8 = jayson;
    9 = active;
    "app_access" = on;
    id = 2;
    "mst_customer" = 1;
    name = "Jayson Tamayo";
    status = active;
    territory = 1;
}, "status": OK, "staff_id": 2, "staff_name": Jayson Tamayo]
```

I use the following Swift code to get the values:

```
    (data: Dictionary<String, AnyObject>, error: String?) -> Void in
                    if error != nil {
                        print(error)
                    } else {

                        if let feed = data["data"] as? NSDictionary ,let entries = data["data"] as? NSArray{
                        for elem: AnyObject in entries{
                              if let staff_name = elem["name"] as? String{
                              print(staff_name)
                              }
                        }
                     }
    }
```

I am trying to get the name by using the keys name or staff_name. But I always get nil.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you want to access staff_name, which is not in "data" variable ... you can simply get that like

```
 if error != nil {
     print(error)
  } else {
      if let name = data["staff_name"] as? String{
          print(name)
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for elem: AnyObject in entries{
    if let songName = elem["name"] as? String{
       print(songName)
    }
}

//replace above code with below code

if let songName : String = entries["name"] as? String{
   print(songName)
}
```

Comment: I get error: Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type 'int' - here entries["name"]

Comment: what is the value of "songName" ??

Comment: I don't know. I can't run it since there is an error.